# What does "beggars belief" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does *beggars belief* mean, in general and in this sentence?

> It beggars belief that removing the tag was so urgent that you couldn't wait for a response more than 40 minutes before removing it.

Comment: This expression's popularity suddenly rocketed in the UK around 1980. One assumes there was some reason why. [See Ngram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beggars+belief%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+beggars+belief%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeggars%20belief%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeggars%20belief%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means that something is as close to unbelievable as it can get. To *beggar* something is to turn it into a pauper, squash it flat, eradicate it, or [unembiggen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embiggen) it.

Webster's:

> **beggar belief** (or **description** ) be too extraordinary to be believed or described.

Edit: Oh, by the way, *beggar* is used as a verb here.

Edit: Oh, yeah, so in this sentence it means "I can't believe you couldn't wait for more than 40 minutes for a response."

Comment: That's probably the reason I didn't understand the meaning: I thought _beggars_ was used as noun.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: You could replace *beggar* with *defies* in that phrase, indeed I sometimes hear it that way.

Comment: What dialect of English is this? I've never heard it in American English.

Comment: It *is* a perfectly cromulent word.

Comment: @BrettAllen, certainly exists in British and Australian English

Comment: It is used in America, but infrequently.  You will hear it mostly from older people.  Google says it's usage has steadily declined since 1900.